# Ruby on Rails: Application.js ordering issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I decided to try and add Parsley to my rails application. But before I get to deal with that at all, I already stopped all of the javascript and datatables from working just by adding `//= require parsley`to my application.js file.

So here it is:

```
//= require jquery
//= require parsley
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap3
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require_tree .
```

All I did was add that one line, and everything broke. So I *know* the order matters, but moving it around hasn't produced results. So I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this. I feel it's either more finicky than it should be, or I'm missing something very basic.

After I placed it there, I ran `rake assets:clean` and `rake assets:precompile`, because I assumed that would work...

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was restart the server, and place the new line of code under `//= require jquery`. Should I remove my post, or leave it for future confused newbies like myself?

Comment: What do you mean "place the new line of code under `//= require jquery`?" A blank line, a line with `//=` or ?
Thanks because I'm having a related problem.